# If a person does not have proof that Islam is the truth, can he ever become a muslim?

Tags: quran, islamic-philosophy, imaan

Think about it this way. If there really was a proof that Islam is the truth, then everyone in the world would have been muslims by now.

Why are you a muslim? Do you have proof? If you think you have proof, it's likely that someone can refute your proof.

I don't have proof of Islam. Rather, I read the Quran. It didn't have anything that convinced me that Islam is the truth. Rather, when I read the Quran, it just "felt" like the truth. So for me, it's just an inner feeling...but not proof. Am I eligible to be a muslim even though I have no proof? Or will Allah say "I will not accept you as a muslim until you find proof"?

Even though I have no proof, if I keep following that "inner feeling", eventually Islam will start to feel like the truth to me. It will be a sort of "self-brainwash". It's how the mind works. If I keep telling myself that it's the truth, my heart will open up to it.

But nevertheless, why are you a muslim? I'm pretty sure you don't have any actual proof. If you're smart, then you should know that no religion can be proven. And since Allah is the all-knowing, I'm sure He knows this as well. So I believe that Allah does not expect you to find proof. If you just read the basics of Islam and feel like it could be the truth, this should be enough to be a muslim. Proof is not always easy to find. Why would Allah make you go through such a burden?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate or tangential discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Religion is based on faith.
Faith is an emotion.
There is no "proof" for emotional attachments.

One chooses to believe in a god, such as Allah, not because they have proof but they are emotionally attached to the idea and have the feeling such as you described. Some are even a step below this and follow the religion taught by their society - their father believed in it, so did his father and so on.

Comment: You are supposed to answer questions from Islamic perspective when you are answering in Islam stack exchange . Not your personal logic , thanks

Comment: What should I do if the Islamic perspective is not present in the context of the question? or if it is just plain factually or morally wrong?

Comment: That is implicit since this is a islam stack exchange , same question can have different answer in skeptics stack exchange or other religion specific stack exchange websites :-)

Comment: @Tachyons I personally voted up, since it is pretty much the best way to answer this question. Also, an "islamic perspective" is only the perspective of muslim people, which includes personnal logic. Some questions can only be answered by personal logic, whether it comes from a "scholar " or not

Answer (score 0):

If a person does not find proof for Islam, he should learn more and struggle to learn throughout life. Afterall, this is a form of Jihad (struggle for way of truth).

And if you honestly did struggle but failed to do so (died without reaching truth but with honest struggle) , then don't worry:

> Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned. [2:286]

No muslim currently have a super solid perfect faith. We all are improving our Ima'an ( faith ) day by day. I wish you all the best for your journey !